# How to insert the data coming from stored procedure result into temp table with out creating temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which returns 110 columns, I want to insert the data coming from that stored procedure into a temp table.

Here is one solution

```
select *  
into #tempTable 
from users -- it is working fine
```

BUT coming to here

```
EXEC Sp_Users_get 12 into #tempTable
```

it is not working.

Please help me for solution

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC Sp_Users_get 12 
GO
```

See this, I think there may be your answer..

[Select Columns from Stored Procedure Resultset](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/26/sql-server-select-columns-from-stored-procedure-resultset/)

Check this out also

[How to INSERT data from Stored Procedure to Table – 2 Different Methods](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/)

Comment: i don't want to Create Temp table with columns. i need insert store procedure result into temp table with dynamic columns...

Comment: Use `User Defined Function` instead of `Stored Procedure`, because `UDF`s that return tables can be treated as another rowset.. I think after then you also need not temp table..

Comment: But my store procedure give result with dynamic columns.. here columns are not fixed to create UDF or Temp table with columns....

Comment: check out second method of OPENROWSET

Comment: i think it is possible to do using secound method but it is getting error in Azure database ..... i need to check out little bit deeply...